# Creating ftp accounts with Perl

Tags: perl, ftp

I wondering is it possible to make script for creating ftp accounts in perl?

I have Unix server.

Comment: If you can do it on the command line, you can do it in perl (or shell, or python, or C, or...). It depends on your ftp server.

Comment: What version of "Unix". How do you create accounts manually (command line, web interface?). What software and versions is your FTP server?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new in unix and i never tried to do such thinks.

Answer (score 2):

I made a module to manage vsftpd accounts a few years ago from perl script. Maybe should I upload it to CPAN. Here's the test file that gives an idea how to use it :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


use strict;
use warnings;

#  test script for ftpuser.pm

use Test::More 'no_plan';
# use Test::Exception;
# if Test::Exception not available
sub dies_ok(&$) {
my $coderef = shift;
my $message = shift;

eval $coderef;

ok( $@, $message)
}

# sub not_ok
sub not_ok(&$) {
my $coderef = shift;
my $message = shift;

eval $coderef;

ok( $@, $message)
}

###


# module to test
use ftpuser;

###########################
# tests OK
# open user database
ok( my $userdb = ftpuser->open_db(), "opening user base");

# open another one
ok( my $userdb2 = ftpuser->open_db('virtual_users_login.db'), "opening user base 2");

# close db
ok( $userdb->close_db(), "closing database" );

# add a user
ok($userdb2->add(user => 'user1'), "add user");

# add user with group
ok($userdb2->add(user => 'user2', group => 'geftp' ), "add user with group");


# ajouter un utilisateur (password fourni)
ok($userdb2->add(user => 'user3', password => 'testpass'), "ajout utilisateur 3");

# add user with group and password
ok($userdb2->add(user => 'user4',group => 'geftp', password => 'testpass2'), "add user with group and password");

# delete users
for my $i ( 1..4) {
        ok($userdb2->remove("user$i"), "deleting user $i");
}

###########################
# tests NOT OK

# add a user without name
dies_ok( sub{$userdb2->add(user => '')}, "add user");

# add an existing user
dies_ok(  sub{$userdb2->add(user => 'user2')}, "user already exists");

# delete a non existing user
dies_ok(  sub{$userdb2->remove(user => 'user1')}, "delete non existing user");
```